# Sometimes VNDetectFaceLandmarksRequest fails with unspecified error

Tags: ios, exception, vision

In my iOS application I use VNImageRequestHandler and VNDetectFaceLandmarksRequest to identify face bounding box and pupils. In my log server I see an error:

Error Domain=com.apple.vis Code=9 encountered an unexpected condition: Unspecified error .

It looks like this error only occurs to **some users**, but for these users it happens multiple times. I couldn't find in the Apple's documentation any way to obtain more data about this error.

```
let imageRequestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer, orientation: .leftMirrored ,options: requestOptions)
do {
    try imageRequestHandler.perform([faceDetectionRequest])
} catch {
    LOG(error) // send log to server
}
```